# How to implement derivative, and create a delay of dozens of clock cycles?

Tags: vhdl, delay

I have uart entity which have the following signals (I write only the relevant - for tx)

```
-- The output data: 8 bit - this is the UART receiver
-- Data is only valid during the time the STB is high
-- Acknowledge the data with a pulse on ACK, which is confirmed by
-- revoking STB.
-- When the following start bit is received the data becomes
-- invalid and the STB is revoked. So take care about fetching the
-- data early enough, or install your own FIFO buffer
DATA_STREAM_OUT     : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
DATA_STREAM_OUT_STB : out std_logic;
DATA_STREAM_OUT_ACK : in  std_logic;
TX                  : out std_logic;
```

I have another block which its enable input should changed to high for only one clock when there is a change of the `DATA_STREAM_OUT_ACK` (high to low) plus delay of 50 clk cycles.

I guess I should derive `DATA_STREAM_OUT_ACK`, but I'm not sure hot to implement this, and also the delay (may be with counter).

Comment: What have you got so far for implementing your delay? What problems did you see?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. In this part of StackExchange we discuss about code errors. If you want to discuss electronic design (even in VHDL), you should ask you question on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius - thanks! I sosn't know there is such part of electrical. cool!:)

Comment: @scary_jeffderivative -  I don't know how to implement derivative (I'm new to vhdk and it's my first time).

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius I don't agree with shifting design questions to the electrical engineering board. The SO [vhdl] tag is far more popular than the EE.SE [vhdl] tag and our community is already so small that I can't see a benefit to splitting it. Furthermore, design questions tend to have more interesting and globally applicable answers than our regular fare of low quality questions (i.e. "why doesn't it compile when the synthesis error spells it out", or worse: "I don't understand the basics of what HDLs are for").

Comment: @QuantumRipple so we differ in opinion. In this case, his question was answered directly on EE [link](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296570/how-to-implement-derivative-and-create-a-delay-of-dozens-of-clock-cycles/296577?noredirect=1#comment682477_296577)... Here nothing yet...q.e.d.

Comment: @QuantumRipple -  this isn't a programming question, the [topic rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are different than [EESE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You'll find the VHDL tags here and at EESE inhabited by the same denizens. There's a [philosophical issue](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) making it undersirable to smear topics, Stackoverflow isn't the place to search for hardware design answers. Too much crossover and vhdl could get migrated to EESE. Would VHDL programming question or answer quality suffer?

Comment: @user1155120 I'd love to discuss this more in  depth; I wish there was a tag specific meta as this is quickly becoming off topic as comments for this question. I think that VHDL is something of a special case; it isn't meant for software development and thus will never satisfy most of the "on topic" bullets, it actually may be better suited to be wholly on EESE, but SO is de facto primary home of HDL questions (~4000 vs ~1500) and SO itself is more widely recognized than EESE. Design issues are for HDL users similar to questions about "a software algorithm" for traditional programmers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/296570/137088). For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have access to a `data_stream_out_ack` signal (it's an input, so it comes from somewhere else), and you want to detect high to low transitions, all you need is a flop and a little logic. A shift register can give you a 50 cycle delay.

Using a shift register instead of a counter will also prevent you from losing old events if a new event comes along within 50 cycles of the old event. It will also use less logic than a counter implementation at such a shallow depth; 50 cycles is just one SRL (technology dependent).

I used your existing naming convention with some added suffixes. You might want to use something shorter.

```
...
   signal data_stream_out_ack_d  : std_logic; --one cycle delay of _ack
   signal data_stream_out_ack_fe : std_logic; --falling edge (delayed one cycle from the first '0' cycle)
   signal data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed : std_logic_vector(50 downto 2); --index indicates delay relative to first '0' cycle of _ack
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            data_stream_out_ack_d  <= data_stream_out_ack; --store what _ack was
            data_stream_out_ack_fe <= data_stream_out_ack_d and not data_stream_out_ack; --if _ack was '1' and is now '0' (a falling edge) produce a pulse
            data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed <= data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed(49 downto 2) & data_stream_out_ack_fe; --shift register to produce delay
            --data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed(50) pulses 50 cycles after _ack experiences a falling edge
        end if;
    end process;
...
```

Comment: I like your naming convention with `_fe`. I never saw someone else using it ... However, a configurable delay unit with one or more taps is provided by [PoC.misc.Delay](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/misc_Delay.vhdl). Functions like [TimingToCycles](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/physical.vhdl#L196-L197) can be used to convert a given timing as type `TIME` and return the number of cycles based on a used clock frequency.

Comment: @Paebbels There's certainly nothing wrong with using that component or function. It's well suited for people who use a more structural style. In my work, delays are almost always defined in cycles, so the time conversion isn't required (looks useful for when I'd need it though!). I also don't find it worthwhile to instantiate a component instance using 26 lines (13 for component definition, 12 for instance, 1 signal definition for output) versus a two line shift register (one for functionality, and one signal definition) that more clearly shows exactly what the underlying logic is.

Comment: I just wanted to outline that there are already implemented solutions on the net :). ... A component is not needed. You can instantiate entities directly. You don't need to assign `Reset` and `Enable` because these have default expressions :). ... Using pure cycle based delays is not very portable. E.g. if your entity shall run on another FPGA or board with a different clock frequency, you have to recalculate all delays. PoC components resize/configure themselves :).

Comment: Can you give example also for the flop and a little logic for detecting high to low transitions?

Comment: @amit rot that's what the code sample in the answer is. The `_fe` signal goes high for one cycle when `data_stream_out_ack` goes from high to low.

Comment: @QuantumRipple - and how I ensure that the `data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed` will be high only for one cycle?

Comment: @QuantumRipple - and what if I need a delay which is more than 50 cycles? Is the shift register still preferable?

Comment: and how exactly I get the final enable?

Comment: I added a few comments to clarify what the code sample is doing. `data_stream_out_ack_fe_delayed(50)` IS the enable signal according to what you said you needed. You hook it to the other block's enable port. `_ack_fe_delayed(50)` is only high for one cycle because `_ack_fe` is only high for one cycle (basic shift registers match the input, but delayed) because it's not possible for the new value of `_ack` to be `'0'` and the old value of `_ack` to be `'1'` two cycles in a row. If the new value of `_ack` is `'0'` this cycle, then by definition, the old value will be `'0'` next cycle.